# Time Complexity/Cost of External Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I got this from a [link](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs186/sp03/section/mreview2.pdf) which talks about external merge sort.

From slide 6 Example: with 5 buffer pages, to sort 108 page file

- Pass0: [108/5] = 22 sorted runs of 5 pages each (last run only with 3 pages)
- Pass1 [22/4] = 6 sorted runs of 20 pages each (last run only with 8 pages)
- Pass2: [6/3] = 2 sorted runs, 80 pages and 28 pages
- Pass 3: [2/2] = 1 Sorted file of 108 pages

Question: My understanding is in external merge sort, in pass 0 you create chunks and then sort each chunk. In remaining passes you keep merging them.
So, applying that to the above example, since we have only 5 buffer pages, in Pass 0 its clear we need 22 sorted runs of 5 pages each.

1. Now, why are we doing sorted runs for remaining passes instead or merging ?
2. How come it tells for pass 1, 6 sorted runs of 20 pages each when we have only 5 buffer pages ?
3. Where exactly is merge happening here ? and how is N reducing in each pass i.e from 108 to 22 to 6 to 2 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

External Merge Sort is necessary when you cannot store all the data into memory. The best you can do is break the data into sorted runs and merge the runs in subsequent passes. The length of a run is tied to your available buffer size.

**Pass0**: you are doing the operations IN PLACE. So you load 5 pages of data into the buffers and then sort it in place using an in place sorting algorithm. 
These 5 pages will be stored together as a run.

**Following passes**: you can no longer do the operations in place since you're merging runs of many pages. 4 pages are loaded into the buffers and the 5th is the write buffer. The merging is identical to the merge sort algorithm, but you will be dividing and conquering by a factor of B-1 instead of 2. When the write buffer is filled, it is written to disk and the next page is started.

**Complexity**:
When analyzing the complexity of external merge sort, the number of I/Os is what is being considered. In each pass, you must read a page and write the page. Let N be the number of pages. Each run will cost 2N. Read the page, write the page.
Let B be the number of pages you can hold buffer space and N be the number of pages.
There will be ceil(log_B-1(ceil(N/B))) passes. Each pass will have 2N I/Os. So O(nlogn).

In each pass, the page length of a run is increasing by a factor of B-1, and the number of sorted runs is decreasing by a factor of B-1.
Pass0: ceil(108 / 5) = 22, 5 pages per run
Pass1: ceil(22 / 4) = 6,  20 pages per run
Pass2: ceil(6 / 4 ) = 2,  80 pages per run
Pass3: ceil(2 / 4 ) = 1 - done, 1 run of 108 pages

Comment: Let's assume the size of all pages is equal. You load 4 pages from 108 pages and store it in the 4 input buffer pages then merge data into result buffer. Now, how can the result buffer hold the data that is size of the 4 input buffer pages  ?

Comment: All pages are the same size, aside from the last one. In pass 0, you load the 5 pages and sort them in place. It doesn't hold all 4 pages at a time. It only holds the first page of each run, think of each run as a linked list. At the end of each page is a pointer to where the next page in the run is. The data is sorted, so data on page 2 is going to be logically after the data on page 1. I think you're mixing up what a page and a run is. Runs are comprised of several pages, pages contain data.

Comment: For Pass 1, you copy 4 pages from disk into the 4 input pages in RAM, then merge those pages into output page which is in RAM. Is that output page 4 times the size of the other input pages ? You see what I am trying to say ?

Comment: Ohh ok. Well, yes. The input and output is 1 to 1, so if you read in 108 pages, 108 pages will be written to the disk. But the number of pages per run is increasing with each pass. You write 1 page to ram, when it fills up, you write it to disk. Then it empties, and fills again, after it fills it is written to disk after the previous page. If the buffer can hold 250 #s, then 200 will be from 4 pages, once 50 sorted numbers are written to the output buffer, it is saved to disk and cleared. Whenever an input buffer runs out of numbers, the next page is read in. Hope this helps.

Comment: In a weird case like this where the number of pages is very small, so it matters that it's discrete, you could do less merging work by merging three 20page runs between pass1 and pass2.  Then pass2 will be a single 4-way merge.  That reduces the total amount of data movement.  In a real situation, with thousands to millions of memory pages available, your ideal merge width is probably limited by something other than number of pages.  (e.g. avoiding too many I/O seeks)

Answer (score 0):

A. Since it NEVER mentions merging, I'd assume (hope) that the later "sorting" passes are doing merges.

B. Again, assuming this is merging, you need one buffer to save the merged records, and use one of the remaining buffers for each file being merged: thus, 4 input files, each w/ 5 pages: 20 pages.

C. Think I've answered where merge is twice now :)

Comment: I dont see where 4 input files came from ? You are dealing with pages here. I can use 4 buffer pages out of 5, to load the 4 pages out of 108 pages and store the result in the last page. But that doesnt seem to be the case as explained above. And in pass two how did it become 6/3 ?

Comment: @FrankQ.: Sorry; I learned this using files instead of pages.  But the pages are being grouped into larger sets, to hold longer sequences of records.  You want to reserve one buffer-page for each group, pulling in each page in sequence from that group as the merge gets to it.  For pass 2, the groups are now 20 pages in size (from 4 groups of size 5), so there are only 6 groups.